# How to call nested apis in Springboot

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Assume we have an api - **/student/getStudentDetails/{id}** which returns a JSON response containing the succeeding internal rest api  (**/student/getAdvancedStudentDetails/{id}**).

```
{
   id:123,
   name:Alex,
   nextapi:/student/getAdvancedStudentDetails/123
}
```

Here when we get the response from first api - /student/getStudentDetails, we need to process the JSON response and take out the second api from the first api and call it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean that *`/student/getStudentDetails/{id}`* calls internally to *`/student/getAdvancedStudentDetails/{id}`*? Or do you mean that the latter depends on the former?

Comment: It should call internally. I have edited the text with possible json response.

Comment: I see yout point. But what's your question? Is it related to the way the client needs to make the call? Or is it related to the way the server needs to process the request?

Comment: How are you filtering out the advanced student ?

Comment: The backend service needs to call it further based on the response from the first api even async. The student example is just an assumption but the need is to get the HATEOAS kind of response from the first service and then the nextapi is called from the first api.

Is this possible??

Comment: I'm not really used to HATEOAS, but as far as I'm concerned, the current object should own the link to itself. Additionally, my guess is that it's the client the one responsible for making further requests depending on its necessities. E.g. a client calls to *getStudentDetails* and it may call to *getAdvancedStudentDetails*. Besides, Spring's [Rest HATEOAS](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/) does it pretty well.

Comment: Yes. You do what you say in the answer: parse the JSON, extract the URL, and send a request to the URL the same way you sent a request to the first one. Not sure what the concrete problem is. Have you tried anything? Where is your code?

Comment: Thanks all of you. Will try coding it and come back to you all.

Answer (score 0):

Your first response for first api  "GET student details" only returns high level details of student and one of field "nextapi" in response has URL to GET more details about student.

In Your first response "nextapi" is customer field defined by you and it only has 
URL without host and port details of sever.  So Consumer of api, will have to parse First response. Create full http url and call the next api to get further details of student. It will not happen automatically.

eg http://localhost:8080/student/getAdvancedStudentDetails/123

{
   id:123,
   name:Alex,
   nextapi:/student/getAdvancedStudentDetails/123
}

Note : 
If your response had full http url for get advance details of student and if api was not secure api. Then if you view first Json, it might give you link for next api, which you can click and see advance details. You can give it try.